# Postman post request returns 200 but retrofit returns 500

Tags: postman, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit

When i make a post request from postman to sent the fcm device token to nodejs server everything works as expected. When itry to make the same call from android device i get the error: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 500. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'd guess that the calls are not the same. Hard to help you without more information.

Comment: You are right. I found the problem in body parameters. Thanks anyway!